# Speeding up evaluation of many scipy splines over the same set of knots

Tags: performance, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a few quick questions with regards to speeding-up spline function evaluation in scipy (version 0.12.0) and I wish to apologize in advance for my novice understanding of splines. I am trying to create an object for scipy.integrate.odeint integration of a chemical kinetics problems using spline lookups for reaction rates (1.e2-1.e3 functions of ode system variables) and generated c-code for all of the algebra in the ODE system of equations. In comparison to a previous implementation that was purely in python, evaluating the c-code is so much faster than the spline interpolations that the evaluation of splines is the bottleneck in the ODE function. In trying to remove the bottleneck, I have reformed all of the reaction rates into splines that exist on the same knot values with the same order while having different smoothing coefficients (In reality I will have multiple sets of functions, where each function set was found on the same knots, has the same argument variable, and at the same derivative level, but for simplicity I will assume one function set for this question).

In principle this is just a collection of curves on the same x-values and could be treated with interp1d (equivalently rewrapping splmake and spleval from scipy.interpolate) or a list of splev calls on tck data from splrep.

```
In [1]: %paste
import numpy
import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import *
#Length of Data
num_pts = 3000
#Number of functions
num_func = 100
#Shared x list by all functions
x = numpy.linspace(0.0,100.0,num_pts)
#Separate y(x) list for each function
ylist = numpy.zeros((num_pts,num_func))
for ind in range(0,num_func):
   #Dummy test for different data
   ylist[:,ind] = (x**ind + x - 3.0)

testval = 55.0

print 'Method 1'
fs1 = [scipy.interpolate.splrep(x,ylist[:,ind],k=3) for ind in range(0,num_func)]
out1 = [scipy.interpolate.splev(testval,fs1[ind]) for ind in range(0,num_func)]
%timeit [scipy.interpolate.splev(testval,fs1[ind]) for ind in range(0,num_func)]

print 'Method 2 '
fs2 = scipy.interpolate.splmake(x,ylist,order=3)
out2 = scipy.interpolate.spleval(fs2,testval)
%timeit scipy.interpolate.spleval(fs2,testval)

## -- End pasted text --
Method 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 ms per loop
Method 2 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop
```

As far as I understand spline evaluations, once the tck arrays have been created (either with splrep or splmake) the evaluation functions (splev and spleval) perform two operations when given some new value xnew:
1) Determine relevant indicies of knots and smoothing coefficients
2) Evaluate polynomial expression with smoothing coefficients and new xnew

### Questions

Since all of the splines (in a function set) are created on the same knot values, is it possible to avoid step (1, relevant indices) in the spline evaluation once it has been performed on the first function of a function set? From my looking at the Fortran fitpack files (directly from [DIERCKX](http://www.netlib.org/dierckx/), I could not find the .c files used by scipy on my machine) I do not think this is supported, but I would love to be shown wrong.

The compilation of the system c-code as well as the creation of all of the spline tck arrays is a preprocessing step as far as I am concerned; if I am worried about the speed of evaluating these lists of many functions, should be looking at a compiled variant since my tck lists will be unchanging?

One of my function sets will likely have an x-array of geometrically spaced values as opposed to linearly spaced; will this drastically reduce the evaluation time of the splines?

Thank you in advance for your time and answers.
Cheers,
Guy

Comment: The DIERCKX indeed code doesn't support vector-valued splines (which is what you'd want to have here); Scipy uses that code directly, it's not ported to C. Fixing this is on the roadmap for Scipy, but not sure it will be in the next release. In the meanwhile, you can just write a spline evaluation routine yourself --- it takes only 50 lines in Fortran and is fairly simple to do. See splev.f and fpbspl.f in DIERCKX.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the info. I was wondering if there was anything that I had missed being offered by the scipy or fitpack libraries, but as you said, writing a vectorized version shouldn't be too difficult. Thanks again.